# Spring Neo4j not save data

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I have created new app which should save Person object to neo4j by repository. But When I use findAll method I don't have any itmes.

**I'm using Spring Boot and here is my conf:**

```
package com.example;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Created by Sebastian on 2015-11-07.
 */
@Configurable
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration{

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        Neo4jServer server = new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474","user","password");
        return server;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.example");
    }

}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {

    Collection<Person> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    Person findByNick(String nick);
}
```

**Person:**

```
    @Data
    @NodeEntity
    public class Person implements Serializable{

            @GraphId
            private Long id;

            //@Index(unique = true)
            private String nick;

            private String firstName;

            private String lastName;

            //private LocalDate birthDay;

            private String password;

           // @Index(unique = true)
            private String email;
```

**PersonService**:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

    //static PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person savePerson(Person user) {
        final String methodName = "SavePerson";
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            user = personRepository.save(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(methodName+" time: "+end);
        System.out.println(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The method `savePerson(Person user)` doesn't throw the exception and returns object so it should work.

I don't know where is the problem. When I change the password to server my up is throwing exception, so it connects to the server but not commit data.

**Edited**
I've read the logs and I can't see nothing wrong but still not work :(

```
2015-11-08 12:30:54.235 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : beginTransaction() being called on thread: 18
2015-11-08 12:30:54.235 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Neo4jSession identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@63ed2891
2015-11-08 12:30:54.236 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction
2015-11-08 12:30:54.307 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : Status code: 201
2015-11-08 12:30:54.310 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Sun, 08 Nov 2015 11:31:54 +0000"},"errors":[]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.311 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : Creating new transaction with endpoint http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4
2015-11-08 12:30:54.313 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Obtained new transaction: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4, tx id: org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.LongTransaction@2fcb12d7
2015-11-08 12:30:54.329  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.s.d.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration    : Initialising Neo4jSession
2015-11-08 12:30:54.334 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassPathScanner  : Classpath elements:
2015-11-08 12:30:54.334 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassPathScanner  : E:\Workspace\workspace_JaVa\neo4j-example\build\classes\main\com\example
2015-11-08 12:30:54.335 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.MainController -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.336 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration -> org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.336 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Noe4jExampleApplication -> org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
2015-11-08 12:30:54.337 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Person -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.337 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.PersonRepository -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.PersonService -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.TraceInterpreter -> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Starting Post-processing phase
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Building annotation class map
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Building interface class map for 11 classes
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - MainController implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - PersonService implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - TraceInterpreter implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - CustomizableTraceInterceptor implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Noe4jExampleApplication implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Neo4jConfiguration implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.338 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - SpringBootServletInitializer implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Person implements 1 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :    - java.io.Serializable
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - PersonRepository implements 1 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :    - org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Object implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.339  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Registering default type converters...
2015-11-08 12:30:54.340 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lcom/example/Person;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.340 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.341 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.341 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/example/Person;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.341 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.341 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lcom/example/Person;)Lcom/example/Person;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.341 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.MainController
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.PersonService
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.TraceInterpreter
2015-11-08 12:30:54.342 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor
2015-11-08 12:30:54.343 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Noe4jExampleApplication
2015-11-08 12:30:54.343 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.344 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
2015-11-08 12:30:54.344 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Person
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - No ClassInfo found for interface class: java.io.Serializable
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.PersonRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - No ClassInfo found for interface class: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Checking for @Transient classes....
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing complete
2015-11-08 12:30:54.345  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : 11 classes loaded in 11 milliseconds
2015-11-08 12:30:54.353 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassPathScanner  : Classpath elements:
2015-11-08 12:30:54.353 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassPathScanner  : E:\Workspace\workspace_JaVa\neo4j-example\build\classes\main\com\example
2015-11-08 12:30:54.354 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.MainController -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.355 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration -> org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.355 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Noe4jExampleApplication -> org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
2015-11-08 12:30:54.356 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.Person -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.356 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.PersonRepository -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.357 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.PersonService -> java.lang.Object
2015-11-08 12:30:54.357 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Processing: com.example.TraceInterpreter -> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor
2015-11-08 12:30:54.357  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Starting Post-processing phase
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Building annotation class map
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Building interface class map for 11 classes
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - MainController implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - PersonService implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - TraceInterpreter implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - CustomizableTraceInterceptor implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Noe4jExampleApplication implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Neo4jConfiguration implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - SpringBootServletInitializer implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Person implements 1 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :    - java.io.Serializable
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - PersonRepository implements 1 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :    - org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - Object implements 0 interfaces
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Registering default type converters...
2015-11-08 12:30:54.358 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lcom/example/Person;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.359 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.359 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.360 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/example/Person;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.361 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.362 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lcom/example/Person;)Lcom/example/Person;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.362 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;
2015-11-08 12:30:54.363 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.363 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Could not load class for descriptor (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.MainController
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.PersonService
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.TraceInterpreter
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Noe4jExampleApplication
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Person
2015-11-08 12:30:54.364 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - No ClassInfo found for interface class: java.io.Serializable
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.Neo4JPersistanceConfiguration
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing: com.example.PersonRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   :  - No ClassInfo found for interface class: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Checking for @Transient classes....
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : Post-processing complete
2015-11-08 12:30:54.365  INFO 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor   : 11 classes loaded in 12 milliseconds
2015-11-08 12:30:54.376 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : --------- new request ----------
2015-11-08 12:30:54.376 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : getOrCreateTransaction() being called on thread: 18
2015-11-08 12:30:54.376 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Session identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@77914ccb
2015-11-08 12:30:54.376 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : There is no existing transaction, creating a transient one
2015-11-08 12:30:54.385 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper   : context initialised with 0 relationships
2015-11-08 12:30:54.386 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper   : visiting: Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)
2015-11-08 12:30:54.386 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper   : Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com) has changed
2015-11-08 12:30:54.388 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper   : mapping references declared by: Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com) 
2015-11-08 12:30:54.456 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.request.SessionRequestHandler    : {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ($103) WHERE id($103)={$103} SET $103:`Person`, $103+={$103_props}","parameters":{"$103":103,"$103_props":{"nick":"Nick","firstName":"Name","lastName":"Last name","password":"password","email":"test@email.com"}},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.456 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest   : POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ($103) WHERE id($103)={$103} SET $103:`Person`, $103+={$103_props}","parameters":{"$103":103,"$103_props":{"nick":"Nick","firstName":"Name","lastName":"Last name","password":"password","email":"test@email.com"}},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.477 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest   : Response is OK, creating response handler
2015-11-08 12:30:54.482 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse    : Closing HttpResponse
2015-11-08 12:30:54.482 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : Appending transaction context org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.compiler.CypherContext@30706412
2015-11-08 12:30:54.482 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : commit invoked
2015-11-08 12:30:54.482 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : Synchronizing transaction context org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.compiler.CypherContext@30706412 with session context
2015-11-08 12:30:54.482 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : checking cypher context object: Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)
2015-11-08 12:30:54.483 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : remembering Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)
2015-11-08 12:30:54.483 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : number of objects: 1
2015-11-08 12:30:54.483 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse    : Closing HttpResponse
2015-11-08 12:30:54.484 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : --------- new request ----------
2015-11-08 12:30:54.484 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : getOrCreateTransaction() being called on thread: 18
2015-11-08 12:30:54.484 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Session identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@77914ccb
2015-11-08 12:30:54.484 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : There is no existing transaction, creating a transient one
2015-11-08 12:30:54.488 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.request.SessionRequestHandler    : {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = { id } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p","parameters":{"id":103},"resultDataContents":["graph"],"includeStats":false}]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.488 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest   : POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = { id } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p","parameters":{"id":103},"resultDataContents":["graph"],"includeStats":false}]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.509 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest   : Response is OK, creating response handler
2015-11-08 12:30:54.513 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse    : Closing HttpResponse
2015-11-08 12:30:54.513 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse    : Closing HttpResponse
false
Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)
SaveUser time: 191
Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)
2015-11-08 12:30:54.514 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4/commit
2015-11-08 12:30:54.516 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : Status code: 200
2015-11-08 12:30:54.516 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.o.s.transaction.TransactionManager   : {"results":[],"errors":[]}
2015-11-08 12:30:54.516 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.n.ogm.session.transaction.Transaction  : commit invoked
2015-11-08 12:30:54.536 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [Person(id=103, nick=Nick, firstName=Name, lastName=Last name, password=password, email=test@email.com)] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4088741b]
2015-11-08 12:30:54.537 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-11-08 12:30:54.537 DEBUG 3816 --- [qtp463494712-18] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Where is the code where you save the data ? Repository is only for retrieving data from the db.

Comment: Is @Data from project lombok? what happens when you switch those fields to be public.

Comment: When you call the ".save" method are you getting an exception? It is probably being "eaten". Try to surround the .save call with a try{}catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();} . You're probably getting a 401 unauthorized exception

Comment: Repository has a default save method. 
Change to public fields nothing changes. Yes @Data is from lombok.
The save method doesn't throw exception.

Comment: Any idea? I'm looking for the problem but without success :(

Comment: Could you share your codebase? Privately with luanne at graphaware dot com.

Comment: here is all code:
https://github.com/SebJak/neo4j-example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Resolved**

I didn't give up by a lot of hours. I created few projects but all of these had the same results. I couldn't save instance on neo4j server, but finally :) I found solution. When I've created a new Person, I've set the id and here existed problem.

**Solution**:
Do not set the value of an attribute annotated as @GraphId when you create a new instance.

Comment: Thank you! Had some old code that sat the graphId, but now it's gone and everything works.

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Comment: I spent 2 hours, you saved my whole day thanks.

Comment: I found one more observation on this. if we declare the id variable as primitive it would consider the value as default and then merge that node with a node having same id. hence two nodes will be merged