# Spring Data Neo4J (SDN) Saving an entity using Neo4jTemplate

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Newbie to SDN and Neo4j. Using sdn version: 4.1.6.RELEASE) and neo4j version: 3.1.0.

I'm trying a simple programmatic way of persisting an object using Neo4jTemplate without any repository support and it doesn't seem to work.

My code (standalone app):

```
public class Scratchpad {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration()
                .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
                .setCredentials("neo4j", "xxxx")
                .setURI("http://localhost:7474");

        System.out.println(config);

        SessionFactory sf = new SessionFactory(config, "domain");

        Session session = sf.openSession();

        final Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate = new Neo4jTemplate(session);

        PlatformTransactionManager pt =  new Neo4jTransactionManager(session);
        final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(pt);

        transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback<Object>) transactionStatus -> {
            Person p = new Person("Jim", 1);
            p.worksWith(new Person("Jack", 2));
            p.worksWith(new Person("Jane", 3));
            neo4jTemplate.save(p, 2);
            return p;
        });
    }

}
```

My entity (present in package **domain**) looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Person() {
        // Empty constructor required as of Neo4j API 2.0.5
    }

    ;

    public Person(String name, long id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Neo4j doesn't REALLY have bi-directional relationships. It just means when querying
     * to ignore the direction of the relationship.
     * https://dzone.com/articles/modelling-data-neo4j
     */
    @Relationship(type = "TEAMMATE", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    public Set<Person> teammates;

    public void worksWith(Person person) {
        if (teammates == null) {
            teammates = new HashSet<>();
        }
        teammates.add(person);
    }

    public String toString() {

        return this.name + "'s teammates => "
                + Optional.ofNullable(this.teammates).orElse(
                Collections.emptySet()).stream().map(
                person -> person.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

There's no symptom of error in the logs. But when I query Neo4J using the web console, no nodes are present.

Answer (score 2):

On a bit more research, found the problem to be that the @GraphId field should never be set a value.

Explained here:
[Spring Neo4j not save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587662/spring-neo4j-not-save-data)

**Hard Lesson learnt: Never,ever set the @GraphId manually.**

Comment: This is an easy trap to fall into and, as you say, a hard lessoned learned. 
While not everyone will agree with this approach, I often provide a setId() that takes a primitive long and checks to see if the id property is already set or not. If the id is null, I do set the value but, if the id is not null, I simply log a warning that says the id was already set and this setter has taken no action. This allows easy unit testing when you want to work with entities where you explicitly set an id (for convenience) but prevents any negative side effects in real world use.